Running an AutoHotKey script. How can I make this a 2 button script where 1 goes forward in the loop and 2 goes back?
So far, I have a nice script that cycles through the keys f1-f4 when I press 1. However, I want to be able to use the 2 button to go backwards in the loop. How can I accomplish this? i.e. f2 to f1.
#InstallKeybdHook
#UseHook

i:=1
loop
{
    1::
    Random, x, 20, 50
    SendInput, {F%i% down}
    Sleep %x%
    SendInput, {F%i% up}
    i:=i+1
    if i>=5
    {
        i:=1
    }
    return
}

Thanks for the help!
